# How should I size my Spinner Image Size in Android app for different screen size/resolutions?

Tags: android, firebase

I'm trying to develop my first app for the play store which should resize for different screen sizes/resolutions. For some reason the spinner images are showing up extremely small for mdpi virtual device & huawei 9 on firebase. Please see attached file. The other images are very large currently because I removed the ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi and xxhdpi folders to see how it would appear with just xxhdpi images.  I have spinner widths in the layout xml files at 40dp, 50dp, 80dp and 180dp for small, normal, large and xtra large screens respectively.[Screenshot of low res mdpi virtual devise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtSOS.png)
Any ideas why the images would appear so tiny!

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone has sizing/layout issues with Android apps for different screen sizes/display dpis - I highly recommend this sdk https://github.com/intuit/sdp/commits?author=elhanan-mishraky which solved my problem above!